# Unable to access hive using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore, spark-shell

I'm trying to access hive through spark-shell. I'm using Windows 8.
Hive version - 2.1.1
Spark version - 2.4.0
Hadoop version - 2.7.7
To begin with I've entered following code in Spark-shell

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    scala> sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees2(id INT,name STRING, age INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'")
```

My hive-site.xml in the /spark/conf is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration><property> <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name> 
<value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value> 
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
<description>URI for client to contact metastore server</description>
</property>
<property> 
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name> 
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value> 
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property> 
<name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name> 
<description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name> 
<value>NONE</value>
<description> Client authentication types. NONE: no authentication check LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class) </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
<value>True</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
<value>False</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Error logs that I'm getting is as follows

```
    2018-12-26 18:34:01 WARN  HiveConf:2753 - **HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist**
    2018-12-26 18:34:03 WARN  metastore:428 - **Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...**
    2018-12-26 18:34:04 WARN  metastore:428 - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
   2018-12-26 18:34:01 WARN  HiveConf:2753 - HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
2018-12-26 18:34:03 WARN  metastore:428 - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
2018-12-26 18:34:04 WARN  metastore:428 - Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:311)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
  ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
  ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Could not connect to meta store using any
of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilde
r.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.s
cala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
        at <init>(<console>:28)
        at <init>(<console>:33)
        at <init>(<console>:35)
        at <init>(<console>:37)
        at <init>(<console>:39)
        at <init>(<console>:41)
        at <init>(<console>:43)
        at <init>(<console>:45)
        at <init>(<console>:47)
        at .<init>(<console>:51)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at .$print(<console>:6)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:819)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:691)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
        ... 104 more

  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
  ... 96 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException: Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: or
g.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilde
r.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$catalog$SessionCatalog$$requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.s
cala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:311)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateTableCommand.run(tables.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$6.apply(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
        at <init>(<console>:28)
        at <init>(<console>:33)
        at <init>(<console>:35)
        at <init>(<console>:37)
        at <init>(<console>:39)
        at <init>(<console>:41)
        at <init>(<console>:43)
        at <init>(<console>:45)
        at <init>(<console>:47)
        at .<init>(<console>:51)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at .$print(<console>:6)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:819)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:691)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:404)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:425)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runClosure(SparkILoop.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
        ... 104 more

  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:466)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
  ... 101 more
```

How to solve it. Am I missing something or is my configuration wrong?

Comment: Is there any good reason why do you want to execute hive commands using spark instead of using spark-sql?

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: host` ... Likely that `thrift://host:9083` should be a real address, not something you've copied from elsewhere